# Is there a VS2017 keyboard shortcut to change document tab order?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In VsCode I use `ctrl + pgup` `ctrl + pgdn` to navigate left and right between open document tabs, and I use `ctrl + shift + pgup` and `ctrl + shift + pgdn` to shift the position of open document tabs left and right.

I find this very helpful to order my documents when following an execution path down a call stack.

Is there anyway to change the document tab order with the keyboard in VS2017?

Answer (score 1):

My [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension with [Navigator](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/navigator.html) add-in lets you assign keyboard shortcuts to **NavigateToNextTab/NavigateToPreviousTab** and **MoveTabLeft/MoveTabRight** commands.